# Assigning values based conditional on two other variables in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of instances of protests in the US and want to assign certain values to a district variable based on the state and the county. Basically I want to "tell" the code "If an event occured a) in **X** state and b) in one of **Y** districts it belongs in **Z** district. I tried this:

```
#Alabama
dfprotest$district[dfprotest$ADMIN1=="Alabama" & dfprotest$ADMIN2=="Washington" | "Mobile" | "Baldwin" | 
                                                          "Escambia" | "Monroe" | "Clarke"]<- "AL-1"
```

It didn't work though. Anyone want to help an R-noob out?

Comment: Noob (working) way is `dfprotest$ADMIN2=="Washington" | dfprotest$ADMIN2=="Mobile" | dfprotest$ADMIN2=="Baldwin"...`. Better way is `dfprotest$ADMIN2 %in% c("Washington", "Mobile", "Baldwin", ...)`

Comment: Alternately, pro way is to make a look-up table. Create a data frame that has columns `ADMIN1`, `ADMIN2` and `district`, use a merge/join to add the `district` column to `dfprotest`: `dplyr::left_join(dfprotest, district_lookup, by = c("ADMIN1", "ADMIN2"))`.

Comment: Here's a worked example of [using a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64649153/903061).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `dplyr` library `mutate` + `case_when` combination

```
library(dplyr)
dfprotest <- dfprotest %>%
    mutate(district = case_when(ADMIN2 %in% c("Washington", "Mobile", "etc") ~ "AL-1"))
```

Comment: Where does the state variable come in (ADMIN1)?

Comment: i hope this works :|

dfprotest <- dfprotest %>%
    mutate(district = case_when(ADMIN1 == "Alabama" & ADMIN2 %in% c("Washington", "Mobile", "etc") ~ "AL-1"))